# tableau web (print / download PDF) large report from dashboard

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I was wondering if it is possible to print/down large PDF large report from a dashboard that requires many pages with a company logo. I tried view and it is only what is on my screen and the specific sheets from this dashboard does not include the logo which I need.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not big text tables like that :(   Essentially Tableau is a dashboarding tool and what you have created is a massive spreadsheet - that you now want to turn into a PDF? (yikes!!)

I'd revisit your requirements.  Is it easier to pull the data directly from the database as a CSV? and then do some formatting? A PDF will be a nightmare for any user.

Comment: The only reason I would use the PDF was to get my company logo. Does the excel export do that?

Answer (score 0):

Tableau has (in my own opinion) limited features about exporting data in different formats, and it is because it is not a reporting tool (like SAP BusinessObjects for example).

The best way to add a company logo is to add an "Image" block inside your dashboard with the logo. The following image shows how to add in Tableau Online, I can't understand if you're using Tableau Online or Tableau Server, you mention Tableau Web that does not exist :-) .
[image: Tableau Online example]

Now I think that your problem is if you want to repeat the logo on every single page that you export, is this your case?

Comment: I would like a logo on every page when there is a printout.